# error: comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'string' (aka 'char *'))

Tags: c, string, pointers, cs50

I´m starting in C any help will be appreciated.

From a saved string in ´letters´, I want to compare, one by one, if those match the one delivered by the user on argv[]. Moreover, I have a problem on my if clause that I don´t understand.

```
crypt.c:17:18: error: comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'string' (aka 'char *')) [-Werror]
        if (g[i] == argv[1])
            ~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~
```

I don´t agree with the compiler this to be a pointer and an integer as I previously defined. g as a string and argv[] as a string. Can someone shed some light in what I am missing, please? I barely know about pointers, can you offer some theory as well? Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Wrong Input\n");
    }
    string g = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(g); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (g[i] == argv[1])
        {
            printf("True\n");
        }
        else
            printf("False\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `g[i] == argv[1]` --> `g[i] == argv[1][i]`

Comment: And you should also make sure `argv[1]` isn't **shorter** than `g`.

Comment: @StoryTeller Does `argv[1]` have same length of `g`?

Comment: Careful with your tags! You have used the C++ tag, but in C++ the meaning of the "type" `string` is something vastly different from the CS50 `string` type. C is not C++, C++ is not C!

Comment: As for your problem, `g[i]` is a single `char` value which [will be converted to an `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions), and you compare it with `argv[1]` which is a pointer to `char` (i.e. `char *`).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - Huh!? Why do you think I posted another comment?

Comment: Probably it is ridiculous.

Comment: "*[defined] ... argv[] as a string*" In the context of defining a function's parameter this `string argv[]` is equivalent to `string * argv`. So `argv` is a ***pointer*** to (whatever) `string` (is defined to be).

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume `string` is `typedef char *`. (Strings in C are so weird I'd recommend not pretending they're anything but pointers and to not hide that with a `string` type.)

The trouble is `argv` is a `char **`, an array of strings. Whereas `g` is a `char *`, or a string. `g[0]` is the first character of the string, a `char`.  `argv[0]` is the first string, a `char *`.

So `g[i] == argv[1]` is comparing a `char` with a `char *`. You probably mean `g[i] == argv[1][i]`.

Answer (score 0):

`g` is a string, but `g[i]` is not string anymore. (read: https://www.tutorialcup.com/cplusplus/strings.htm#CharacterArray)

Maybe you can check it as a char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

// maybe cs50.h have this line inside:
// typedef char* string;

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if ((argc != 2) || (strlen(argv[1])!=1))
    {
        printf("Wrong Input\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // second argument, and first char
    char arg = argv[1][0];

    string g = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(g); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (g[i] == arg)
        {
            printf("True\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("False\n");
        }
    }
}
```